# How to write java code for FPE (Format Preserving Encryption) functions?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

For FPE, I have passed plaintext as a `38D8DDD0D2` (10 digit) and tweak value as `18AD3A1387A9BCEB9BD223C44391CAB7` (32 digit) for encryption and decryption which are working, but not able to achieve FPE format.

But for FPE (Format Preserving Encryption), the output encryption value should be same format and length as like plaintext (10 digit).

Overall, If I give the input 10 digit string value, then the encryption value would be the same format with 10 digit length, and again after decryption - the same input string will be returned.

Please help me do that. Thanks

Comment: If you use a stream cipher, the output will be the same length as the input. How did you encrypt your plaintext?

Comment: What FPE mode are you using?  You talk about a tweak value, does that indicate you are using FFX mode?

Comment: There are two close votes for not including source code. Either you are asking us to implement everything, which is off topic, or you should really show what you've done. I assume there is something or "not able to achieve FPE format" would really be a stinker.

Comment: I have mentioned my code. Please look into that for better understand.

Comment: I have gone through this below link. https://howtodoinjava.com/security/java-aes-encryption-example/                 Here, if you check properly then you will see secretKey  which I have passed as a tweak value "18AD3A1387A9BCEB9BD223C44391CAB7" and originalString  which I have passed as a plaintext = "38D8DDD0D2". Hope now picture is clear. So I need FPE format after encryption and plaintext will be return after decryption. Please let if my process is wrong and guide me accordingly to achieve the same. Thanks

Comment: Yes Maarten, Your assume is correct, I am not able to achieve FPE format. Could you please send some code/logic how to achieve the same. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing FPE mode with other more common AES modes, e.g., the example code you shared is for ECB mode. Unfortunately using different AES modes in Java is not plug-and-play, each mode has to be used and handled slightly differently.

As for FPE, I don't think its even supported by the default Java JCE. See if you can use [this](https://github.com/idealista/format-preserving-encryption-java) implementation of it instead.

Comment: A more recent implementation is the Mysto library  https://github.com/mysto/java-fpe